# Setting up a proxy with authentication in web.config for internet access

Tags: proxy, web-config, credentials

I need to have my .NET application access the internet, however they only allow me to access the internet through a proxy server with authentication.

On my first attempt I simply configured Internet Options with the proxy and user/pass, it worked, but that configuration only applied to the windows account I was logged with, when someone else logged in with their account they didn't have the proxy setup, plus I think over time it will re-prompt you for the credentials again. So this didn't work.

Second attempt was by following these steps form https://github.com/rollbar/Rollbar.NET/issues/186

using following block in your app.config or web.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy proxyaddress="proxyAddress" usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

and in Credential Manager >> Add a Generic Credential
Internet or network address: your proxy address
User name: your user name
Password: you pass

Again, no luck, I still get asked for authentication:

```
Inner Exception: 
Type Of Exception: System.Net.WebException
Source Of Exception: System
Target Site: GetRequestStream
Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

What am I missing on my approaches? is there a way to propagate the proxy settings to any account/caller from my first attempt? Am I missing something on my second attempt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A RollbarConfig object supports the following properties for proxy related settings: `ProxyAddress`, `ProxyUsername`, `ProxyPassword` for providing custom proxy settings. The same properties can be configured via either XML or JSON config file as well (as `proxyAddress`, `proxyUsername`, `proxyPassword`)